# Git diff command without paramter

Tags: git

I have a question about git diff command without paramters. As far as i understood this command. This command compare changes between staging area and working directory. But sometimes even i have nothing in staging area but still got output when running git diff. Any help would be appreicated

Comment: Does this answer your question? [question about git diff](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7229657/question-about-git-diff)

Comment: Might be a better duplicate - if that doesn’t help, after [reading the docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff) please clarify your question, an example would help. Also please do not tag spam.

Comment: Note that you almost always have things in the staging area. It's just that those things—those files—match (have the same contents as) the files in the *current commit*, so that Git does not *mention* those files. If the files are removed from the staging area, Git will tell you that a deletion is staged for commit (which is true)—so the files *must* be present, to prevent the files from being deleted.

Comment: To make sense of this, realize that each commit contains a *full snapshot of every file*, and `git commit` simply packages up the files that are in the index / staging-area *right then*. So the index / staging-area (two names for the same thing) *must* hold *every file* that is to be committed, in the form that it will have when committed. The `git add` command really means *copy the working tree copy of the file into the index copy*.

Comment: There are a lot of picky little details here that make the above a bit of an oversimplification, but if you just think of Git has having *three* copies of each "active" file—one in the *current commit*, one in the index / staging-area, and one in your working tree—you're on the path to understanding.

Answer (score 0):

For an overview,

- `git diff` shows the difference between worktree and staged changes
- `git diff --cached` shows the difference between staged changes and commited stuff (usually HEAD)
- `git diff HEAD` nicely combines both, showing differences between the worktree and the commited state.

So, if nothing is staged but your `git diff` shows changes, it means your worktree is "dirty", i.e., there are uncommited unstaged changes in your files.